# Replacement of tyres on a BMW X1 XLINE

Tags: bmw

**My car is fitted with pirelli tyres of size 225/50/R18** when taken delivery of the vehicle. The tyre has been creating frequent problems like bursting, punctures etc even on highways. **Can I replace these tyres with Apollo/ MRF tyres of size 225/50/R17 tyre** ***The rime size of Apollo and MRF tyre of this size is available of rim size R17.
Will the R17 Tyre fit in this case.?*** Please answer.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. The last number is the diameter of the inside of the tyre. Your rims are 18 inches in diameter, if you tried to put 17 inch tyres on them they simply won't fit.

If your tyres are bursting often then it's possible you aren't inflating them properly, they are the wrong tyres for the rims you have, your driving style is extraordinarily hard on them, or you're just unlucky. It's also possible you're getting counterfeit tyres, Pirelli is a good, reliable make but there's knock-offs out there made with substandard materials and they are plain dangerous.